# Primitive elements in a free group

Tags: gr.group-theory, geometric-group-theory, free-groups

Let $F$ be a free group of rank $\aleph_0$ and let $H$ be a subgroup for which there exists some $a \in F$ such that $\langle H \cup \{a\} \rangle = F$. Must there be some free basis $B$ for $F$ and a subset $B_0 \subseteq B$ for which $\langle H \cup B_0 \rangle = F$ and $|B_0|$ is bounded by some absolute finite constant $K$?

Can we take $K  = 1$?

Comment: I don't think you are asking what you mean to ask, because as written, you can just take $B$ to be an arbitrary free basis, and $B_0=B$, and $K=\aleph_0$. I *suspect* you want $B_0$ finite, for one thing...

Comment: @ArturoMagidin thanks. I meant that $K$ is finite.